# How to open a web (.html) ressource file with native code (ios app)

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, deep-linking

I have an ios app built with Cordova.
I would like to open a web ressource file (.html) after a deep linking, in a UIWebView with the handleURL ios method.

I know I'm supposed to do this within my cordova JS files, but I would like to know the way to do it natively?

Let's say I define a `my-app` URL scheme and want to open `file1.html`.
What are the ways for doing that?

I have found this:

```
// Load the html as a string from the file system
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// Tell the web view to load it
[WebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

But nothing happens, like it can't find that file.
Why is that?

Comment: Run it in the debugger. What happens exactly .. is your code called? is path nil? is html nil? is your webview nil?

Comment: Hey @LouFranco, thanks, path is nil. but does it work if my html is in a www folder, and not Ressource?

Comment: In a cordova project, the www folder is usually copied into the resource bundle of the app.  Open the Xcode project and see if it's there. Make sure there really is an index.html and it's set to copy into the bundle.

Comment: If your app downloaded the HTML and put it in a documents folder, then you need to set path using that, not a bundle resource lookup.

Comment: @LouFranco hey thanks, actually no, it's just my ionic html files are put there, after I build the ionic project in iOS.

Comment: In the iOS project, is there an `index.html` that is (1) in the project structure (2) marked to be included in the bundle (click it, then make sure the app project is checked on the File Inspector / Target Membership). If so, add a Xcode screenshot showing this to the question.

Answer (score 0):

put all files in a folder and while adding drag drop in project. and select create folder references and copy items if needed. and try to load in UIWebView

Comment: Thank you, very inetersting, do u have another idea in mind?

Comment: do u want to load ur webview with html file which is inside bundle??

Comment: the html files are just inside a www folder in the root.

Answer (score 0):

1. You make a new class that inherits from `NSURLProtocol`.
2. You need to call `[NSURLProtocol registerClass:YOURCLASS]` in your app
3. In your class, implement `+ (BOOL) canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)` to return true if the scheme matches your scheme (e.g. `my-app`)
4. See the docs for `NSURLProtocol` to see how to implement the rest of the functionality.  For simple file system reads, you can implement `startLoading` and call `self.client` callbacks (e.g. `URLProtocol:didLoadData:`).  For more complex things, you might need to override more.

See this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/59982/nsurlprotocol-tutorial

Comment: Thank you, very interesting too, but a bit complex. please have a look at the code I added in the question, any comment about it?